# How to show taxonomy term image on node creation page drupal?

Tags: 7, theming

I have added an image field to my taxonomy terms. I upload images to each term. I just wanted to show term images on node creation page. Currently it showing term name only and showing image after node creation.
I want to show term image on node creation page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of term reference field try [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field with [Entity Reference view widget](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget). This will help you to specify a view for field. Create an entity reference view that shows your additional image field. Select this view in your entity reference field settings.